# How to pull docker image from docker hub private registry into Azure Container Service (ACS)?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub, azure-container-service

I have setup a private registry in Docker hub (hub.docker.com): rbiswas/http-service.
Now I am trying to pull/run this image into Azure Container Service (ACS) cluster vm by following the steps mentioned below:

First I ssh into the ACS cluster using command:

```
ssh -i /home/rbiswas/.ssh/acs_rsa -L 2375:localhost:2375 -N rbiswas@swarmclustermgmt.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200
```

Then I use the following commands in another terminal:

```
docker -H tcp://localhost:2375 login hub.docker.com
docker -H tcp://localhost:2375 run -i -d -p 8080:8080 rbiswas/http-service
```

But I am getting the following error even after successful login:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Not found.
```

But if I make the docker hub registry public, then the docker run command is successful. So how do I pull from a Docker Hub private registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by running pull and run command separately:

```
docker -H tcp://localhost:2375 login
docker -H tcp://localhost:2375 pull rbiswas/http-service
docker -H tcp://localhost:2375 run -i -d -p 8080:8080 rbiswas/http-service
```